# VBS Autofilter cut and paste multiple strings

Tags: excel, vbscript, autofilter

I'm creating a VBS file that I will be launching via cscript in a batch file. I will not be using VBA whatsoever. I've got the ability to Open it, and format it and other things, However I have multiple iterations of auto filter I need to cut from sheet 1 and paste into sheet 2. Sheet 1 is MasterPrinterList and Sheet 2 is Invalid Printers

For instance my problem lies in

```
myXL.ActiveSheet.Range("A:G").AutoFilter 6, "*not used*",,,True
myXL.ActiveSheet.Range("A:G").Select
myXL.Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
myXL.Selection.Copy
myXL.Sheets("Invalid Printers").Select
myXL.Range("A2").Select
myXL.ActiveSheet.Paste
myXL.Sheets("MasterPrinterList").Select
myXL.Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I can get that to work, but Excel freaks out, crashes, and says Server threw exception on the Paste Line.

I want it to use Auto Filter, look in column 6 for Find any cells that contain "*not used*" paste rows that have that into first available row in sheet 2. Then go back to sheet 1 clear auto filter, then re autofilter for "*not being used*" paste to sheet 2 in next available row. Then go back to sheet 1, clear auto filter, then re autofilter for "*moved to*"

etc etc etc. I can fill out each search query for Auto filter, I just can't figure out how to paste properly without crashing excel, and then repeating the search block for different lists.

My first problem is obviously

```
 myXL.Range("A2").Select
```

which needs to be something like first available row rather than specifying the cell to paste in.

Second is how to structure the auto filters to work properly.

I've tried

```
myXL.ActiveSheet.Range("A:G").AutoFilter 6, "*moved to*"
myXL.Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
myXL.ActiveSheet.Range("A:G").Copy
myXL.Sheets("Invalid Printers").Activate

set objRange = myXL.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
objRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Activate
intNewRow = myXL.ActiveCell.Row + 1
strNewCell = "A" & intNewRow

myXL.Range(strNewCell).Select
myXL.ActiveSheet.Paste
myXL.Application.CutCopyMode = False
myXL.Selection.Delete -4162
myXL.ActiveSheet.Range("A:G").AutoFilter
```

Any help..?

Comment: Have you tried doing what you want to do manually in Excel, recording it as a macro? The VBA code generated in the macro may help you debug this issue in the VBS.

Comment: You should really ask a more specific question. For example, _"How do I find the first blank row in my Excel worksheet?"_

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own with playing around. It may be ugly,but it works.. Here is the code

```
myXL.Sheets ("MasterPrinterList").Activate
myXL.ActiveSheet.Range("A:G").AutoFilter 6, "*moved to*"
myXL.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1,0).Select
myXL.Selection.Copy
myXL.Sheets("Invalid Printers").Activate
myXL.ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
myXL.ActiveCell.PasteSpecial 
myXL.Application.CutCopyMode = False

myXL.Sheets ("MasterPrinterList").Activate
myXL.Selection.Delete
myXL.ActiveSheet.Range("A:G").AutoFilter



myXL.ActiveSheet.Range("A:G").AutoFilter 6, "*delete*"
myXL.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1,0).Select
myXL.Selection.Copy
myXL.Sheets("Invalid Printers").Activate
myXL.ActiveSheet.Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(1,0).Select
myXL.ActiveCell.PasteSpecial 
myXL.Application.CutCopyMode = False

myXL.Sheets ("MasterPrinterList").Activate
myXL.Selection.Delete
myXL.ActiveSheet.Range("A:G").AutoFilter
```

So the `myXL.ActiveSheet.Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(1,0).Select` was my answer to finding the first blank fow at the end of a column. And the rest was figuring out the steps and syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggession:

- oWb.ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy oWb.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
- You can iterate through any list of conditions instead of condition "c"
- You can use complex condtions

---

```
' Copy filtered columns to new sheet using VBS
Option Explicit
Const xlCellTypeVisible = 12
Const xlOr = 2
Dim oXL : Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oWb : Set oWb = oXL.Workbooks.Open("d:/PersonalData/YourNameGoesHere/Documents/Book1.xlsx")
Dim filteredCols : filteredCols = "A:B"
oXL.Visible = True
oXL.DisplayAlerts = false

oWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

' oWb.ActiveSheet.Range(filteredCols).AutoFilter 1, "c"
oWb.ActiveSheet.Range(filteredCols).AutoFilter 1, "a", xlOr, "b"    

' both columns of the filetered result
' oWb.ActiveSheet.Range(filteredCols).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy oWb.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
' the first column of the filtered result
' oWb.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy oWb.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
' the second column of the filtered result
oWb.ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy oWb.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

oWb.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Msgbox "Press Enter to continue"

' Removing AutoFilter is not necessary
oWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
oWb.ActiveSheet.Range(filteredCols).AutoFilter 1

oWb.Close
oXL.Quit
Set oWb = Nothing
Set oXL = Nothing


' My Book1.xlsx contained the following rows and columns on Sheet1:
' char  number
' a 1
' b 2
' c 3
' d 4
' k 5
' o 6
' t 7
' n 8
' a 9
' b 10
' c 11
' d 12
' k 13
' o 14
' t 15
' n 16
' a 17
' b 18
' c 19
' d 20
' k 21
' o 22
' t 23
' n 24
```